# Hibernate loading speed

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, servlets

When you perform your first query on an Hibernate application, it will execute some processes before the query. This processes tend to delay a REAL lot of time, at least for my application perspective that contains a web service. When you press the html button, it will delay more than 7 seconds for an update and an unique result select.

What techniques can I use to solve this loading delay?

- I've thought about performing the load while the user is typing the fields before the button press, but this is not what I want (if you need, I can explain those reasons, but extends my question).

Thank you.

Comment: So where is the bottleneck?  Have you analyzed the query that is run?  For example, if you're updating and the "where" clause doesn't use an index it may take a long time.  Be careful - the database may cache too and so the first run is slow and the second run not.

Comment: The bottleneck happens not when the query executes, but when the connection loads.I'm pretty sure the query part is fine!

Comment: @stdunbar here is the codeline where it delay's the most: org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: (user....